# Datagridview combobox data cannot be changed

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I am retrieving data from a dataset into a datagridview which has combobox columns and text columns.
After retriving data , I cannot change any data in the combobox column , it throughs an error as datagridcomboboxcell value is invalid.

How to solve this?

```
sql = "Select  Sequence, ValueDate, AcctID, TransCode, DorC, Amount, Currency, Description1, Description2, LocalEquivalent From tempentries where FCID = " & mdi.Ids.Text & " and transid = " & TransID.Text
         da = New SqlDataAdapter(sql, UnauthCon)
    da.Fill(ds, "TempEntries")

    DGVTransactions.DataSource = ds.Tables("TempEntries")
               DGVTransactions.Refresh()
```

Comment: Show your retrieving code ..

Comment: I think this is connected to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17082721/datagridview-data-load-is-giving-error

Comment: Have you tried to set DisplayMember and ValueMember as I told you in the other question?